# Ready method that split big string into 3 paragraphs C#

Tags: c#, split

i need to split a large string to 3 paragraphs each not less than 1000 character length
with next and previous buttons

Any help

Comment: The string class contains multiple properties like Length and SubString(), do you have a concrete problem you´re facing?

Comment: (as he mentioned next and previous buttons) I guess he's asking how to read and load 1k chars of text into some component

Comment: What do you mean _next and previous buttons_?

Comment: First i am a girl :D not as he mentioned but as she mentioned ...

Comment: I need to keep track on the previous block and the next block to show on previous and next buttons ... i also wanna make sure that spiting in on '\n' found

Comment: I was asking if there is any kind of ready made method that i can use directly without wasting time and effort and debugging .. didn't say it's not doable :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) for splitting your text based on the size. 
A complete application however, I can not deliver.